# How to Add inner class which returns the Widget in GWT UiBinder

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I am Using GWT UiBinder for creating custom component.Main class(Table uibinder) will create custom component table with pager,See below code

**Table.ui.xml:**

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:item="urn:import:"com.example.ui.widgets.item">
    <g:HTMLPanel >
            <item:CustomGrid ui:field="table"></item:CustomGrid>
            <item:Pager ui:field="pager" </item:Pager>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </ui:UiBinder>
```

**Table.java:**

```
package com.example.ui.widgets.item;
    public class Table extends Composite{
        private static TableUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(TableUiBinder.class);

        interface TableUiBinder extends
                UiBinder<Widget, Table> {
        }

        @UiField CustomGrid grid;
        @UiField Pager pager;

        public Table() {
            initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
            }

    class CustomGrid extends CellTable{
    //create custom celltable 
    }

    class Pager{
    //Pagination code
    }
    }
```

How to access(&add) the Inner Class CustomGrid & Pager in UiBinder?What is syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I got you right, but in your code above some things should change. If this does not answer your question please be more precise.

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:item="urn:import:"com.example.ui.widgets.item">
    <g:HTMLPanel >
            <item:CustomGrid ui:field="table"></item:CustomGrid>
            <item:Pager ui:field="pager" </item:Pager>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </ui:UiBinder>
```

So far, so good. Here's the change:

```
package com.example.ui.widgets.item;
    public class Table extends Composite{
        private static TableUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(TableUiBinder.class);

        interface TableUiBinder extends
                UiBinder<HTMLPanel, Table> {
            /* wrapper is HTMLPanel, instance holder is Table */
        }

        @UiField (provided = true)
        CustomGrid table = new CustomGrid(); 
        @UiField (provided = true)
        Pager pager = new Pager();

        public Table() {
            initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

            pager.doSomething();
            table.doSomthingElse();
        }

    class CustomGrid extends CellTable{
    //create custom celltable 
    }

    class Pager{
    //Pagination code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ArcTanH,first one is typo error(UiBinder<HTMLPanel, Table>),My Question is here How to access the inner class..

Comment: code seems correct to me, where do you want to access your inner classes? Where's your problem? Errorcode? Stacktrace?

Comment: Both    <item:CustomGrid ui:field="table"></item:CustomGrid>
            <item:Pager ui:field="pager" </item:Pager> are innerclass of Table..How to access in UiBinder of Table.ui.xml

Comment: Ah okay, guess I got your problem, finally.
Have you considered to make the inner class static? Otherwise, use

@UiField CustomGrid(provided = true) table = new CustomGrid() 

and same for pager.

Comment: could you share your result please?

Comment: Hi ArcTanH,I solve it in some other way,I created htmlpanel in uibinder and taken the htmlpanel reference in .java and added the table & pager to htmlpanel